# How am I supposed to respond to edits on my posts?

Tags: support, edits

When someone modifies a certain part of my post I have no idea what to do next

any help?

Comment: Have the edits made the post better? If so then you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Expanding on Jon's comment: if it was a good edit, learn from it, so your next posts will be clear, concise and invite an answer in the first shot. Best wishes.

Answer (score 12):

Are the changes good? Do they clarify the post? Make it more understandable?

Accept the edit.

Are they bad? Do they completely change the meaning? Are they spam? Do they deface the post?

Reject the edit.

---

You may be seeing the message after the edit has been approved by the community. You can simply leave it be if it is a good edit. If it isn't you can always roll it back.

Comment: Ok the question is that how can I accept or reject?

Comment: @MohammadTaha - if the edit was already approved, you can't.

Comment: @MohammadTaha if edit is not pending, just made (by an user that can do it without review, or it was already reviewed), you can only live with that edit or use "rollback" in revision history.

Answer (score 8):

When someone has edited the post a bit, that means they think that your post is clear this way. But remember you have a right to say whether their belief is true or not. Because after all you have to clarify the question as you see it and not them!

#### When to approve an edit

If you think, that the post has been made better such as:

1. Improved spelling mistakes.
2. Improved coding format, font-styling technique.
3. Improved the word usage and paragraphing.
4. Improved grammar and other punctuation mistakes!

Then, you can approve it, so that your post gets a better view.

#### When to not approve; reject

But if it changes the meanings on the post regardless of being helpful in English standards, just reject the edit!

You must not approve an edit that changes or reverses the meaning of the question.

#### How to take action

You are never always told to take an action, community takes care of that most of the time! But you also get a notification for that. Click on it, and there you will get two options. Approve OR Reject!

#### More

P.S. You can always Roll a post back to a condition where it is in a better condition. This way, the post will go back to the state where it explains the initial problem and post better.

Comment: Oh @Afzaal Ahmad thank you this is what I am looking for<< how to reject a certain edit

Comment: About rollbacks - it's worth noting that if someone rolls your rollback, or edit unwanted changes back, you shouldn't rollback again. That would be an edit war. *flag -> other (needs ♦ moderator attention)* is the proper thing to do in such cases.